# Laravel queues are not working and I'm getting an error

Tags: php, laravel, queue, worker, laradock

I'm working on a project through Laravel, it doesn't work while trying to use a queue, the queue uploads a task to the database, I can check the queue that has been uploaded from the database, but the queue doesn't  run over time.

And you can see the following error message,

The database is well connected, everything is fine until signing up, but I am getting an error while running the queue.

help me pleace

```
enter code hereocal.ERROR: could not find driver {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 0): could not find driver at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(70): PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=bbed...', 'default', 'secret', Array)
#1 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(46): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createPdoConnection('pgsql:host=bbed...', 'default', 'secret', Array)
#2 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/PostgresConnector.php(33): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createConnection('pgsql:host=bbed...', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(184): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\PostgresConnector->connect(Array)
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\{closure}()
#5 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(939): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(137): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdo()
#7 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(113): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->createTransaction()
#8 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php(23): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->beginTransaction()
#9 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php(222): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->transaction(Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(327): Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue->pop('default')
#11 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(336): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->Illuminate\\Queue\\{closure}('default')
#12 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(145): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->getNextJob(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\DatabaseQueue), 'default')
#13 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(117): Illuminate\\Queue\\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\WorkerOptions))
#14 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#15 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand->handle()
#16 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#17 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#18 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#19 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(610): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#20 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#21 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#22 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#23 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(971): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(290): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Queue\\Console\\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(166): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(92): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#28 /var/www/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#29 {main}
```

Comment: Can you share your .evn configuration for the `QUEUE_CONNECTION`. It would be easier to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Seems like you don't have a driver for PostgreSQL

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=bbeda_postgres_1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=bbeda
DB_USERNAME=default
DB_PASSWORD=secret
////////////////



These are the information of the current database, membership registration and data inquiry, not queues, can be used without problems, only the queue is strange